# How to tell Babel to target ES2021?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have the following babel.config.**js**  (not .rc) file:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
       return {
        "presets": [
            "@babel/preset-react",
            [
                "@babel/preset-env",
                {
                    "useBuiltIns": "entry",
                    "corejs": "3.8",
                    targets: {
                        chrome: 97      // January 2022
                    },
                    "modules": false
                }
            ]
        ],
        "plugins": [
            ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", {
                "throwIfNamespace": false, // defaults to true
                "runtime": "automatic" // defaults to classic
            }],
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
            "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign",
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
            ["module:fast-async", { "spec": true }]
        ]
    }
```

I find that even though I have targeted a modern browser (Chrome v97, released Jan 2022) Babel still transpiles async/await to promise-based code.

I would like to target ES2021 so Babel doesn't need to transpile async/await.

Additionally I want to use the ?? and ?. operators. In fact, anything ES2021 supports.

I know there are plugins to emulate most things but the browser I'm targeting already supports ES2021. I just don't know how to tell Babel "don't transpile if browser supports it already.".

How would I do this?

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "scts-expenses",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config tools/webpack/config/build",
    "ci": "webpack --config tools/webpack/config/integration",
    "dev": "webpack --config tools/webpack/config/dev",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/eslint src -c .eslintrc --ext js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/jest",
    "watch-dev": "webpack --config tools/webpack/config/dev --watch"
  },
  "author": "scott",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/node": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
     "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.13",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^23.20.0",
    "eval": "^0.1.4",
    "fast-async": "^6.3.8",
    "filemanager-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.5",
    "imagemin-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.2",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-axe": "^3.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "postcss-css-variables": "^0.13.0",
    "postcss-custom-properties": "^9.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "preact": "^10.10.6",
    "preact-render-to-json": "^3.6.6",
    "preact-render-to-string": "^5.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.5.10",
    "abortcontroller-polyfill": "^1.7.3",
    "core-js": "^3.25.0",
    "custom-event-polyfill": "^1.0.7",
    "element-closest-polyfill": "^1.0.2",
    "es6-object-assign": "^1.1.0",
    "form-request-submit-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "picturefill": "^3.0.3",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "storm-modal": "^1.2.1",
    "storm-tabs": "^1.3.3",
    "unfetch": "^4.2.0",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^8.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm hitting my head against a similar problem.

Comment: @River give my posted solution a try.

Comment: Use [browserlist](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#browserslist-integration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out how to use the latest (or, as modern as I need) features.

The key is to use babel/preset-env *and* deny Internet Explorer as **browser targets**.

I discovered this by tinkering around at https://babeljs.io/repl/ . When I found the settings that produced modern code (no converting await/async to promises, for example) I copied them to my babel config.

Here's my babel config:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
api.cache(true);

return {
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      Object.assign({}, process.env.NODE_ENV === "test"
        ? {
              "loose": true,
                "targets": {
                    "node": 8,
                    "browsers": [">0.25%","not IE"]
                }
          }
          : {
              "useBuiltIns": "entry", 
              "corejs": "3.8", 
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": "defaults, not ie 11, not ie_mob 11"
                },
              "modules": false
          }
        )
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
      ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", {
          "throwIfNamespace": false, // defaults to true
          "runtime": "automatic" // defaults to classic
      }]
    ]
}
```

};

And here's my package.json. Note: I believe some/all of the polyfills referenced (such as es6-object-assign and promise-polyfill) are no longer required. I will remove them in my project - please do not include them in yours unless necessary.

```
{
  "name": "NeverYouMind ;)",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "ci": "webpack --config tools/webpack/config/integration",
    "dev": "webpack --config tools/webpack/config/dev",
    "lint": "node_modules/.bin/eslint src -c .eslintrc --ext js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/jest",
    "watch-dev": "webpack --config tools/webpack/config/dev --watch"
  },
  "author": "Scotty T",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/node": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.13",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^23.20.0",
    "eval": "^0.1.4",
    "fast-async": "^6.3.8",
    "filemanager-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.5",
    "imagemin-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.2",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-axe": "^3.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "postcss": "^7.0.35",
    "postcss-css-variables": "^0.13.0",
    "postcss-custom-properties": "^9.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "preact": "^10.10.6",
    "preact-render-to-json": "^3.6.6",
    "preact-render-to-string": "^5.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.5.10",
    "abortcontroller-polyfill": "^1.7.3",
    "core-js": "^3.25.0",
    "custom-event-polyfill": "^1.0.7",
    "element-closest-polyfill": "^1.0.2",
    "es6-object-assign": "^1.1.0",
    "form-request-submit-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "picturefill": "^3.0.3",
    "promise-polyfill": "^8.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "unfetch": "^4.2.0",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^8.1.0"
  }
}
```